# Get flashing window in delphi (window that needs focus and windows won't set it to front)

Tags: windows, delphi, focus, setforegroundwindow

I was searching on internet how to enable "auto-switch" or "auto-raise" window that has flashing button on taskbar in Windows 7,
and all I can find is how to disable that! I need just opposit, to enable that so i looked at that answers and found registry key
ForegroundLockTimeout. It is set to 200000ms by default i think, so i set it to 1ms, but that doesn't affect anything after Windows XP I guess..
I found that it used to be possible to enable auto switching in Tweak UI from Microsoft, but that doesn't seems to work on Win 7 either.

I tried to program that in Delphi and I can set window on top with SetForegroundWindow, but i can't detect which windows need attention - are flashing.
It is even possible to detect foreground window with GetForegroundWindow, but not window that is flashing so i could set it on top.

So my question is, is it possible in delphi to get hwnd of that window that needs focus in background?

Comment: Do you mean an already flashing window within your process, or any running process?

Comment: I belive he is searching for a way to bring up window of a another process becouse in his own process he would not have any problem in finding the correct window.

Comment: There is no API to query which window is flashing on the Taskbar. You would likely have to take frequent screenshots of the Taskbar itself and parse out the pixels for its buttons to see if they are changing colors at regular intervals. You will likely also have to hook `SetForegroundWindow()` itself in every running process in order to detect which windows are attempting to be brought to the foreground and failing.

Comment: To actually bring a window into the foreground, you need permission from the foreground process if your app is not already running in the foreground. To do that, you will likely have to inject code into the foreground process and have it call `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` to grant permission to your process so it can then call `SetForegroundWindow()`.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Well, i am attempting the really basic thing, if external program (window) needs attention (blink in taskbar), then it should pop up in front (or to get the name/class of that window in delphi code, so i can setforegroundwindow by myself). Shouldn't that be normal thing to enable/disable in windows? I guess that microsoft removed that by disabling ForegroundLockTimeout because of exploiting or something.

Comment: The flashing is done by calling FlashWindow of FlashWindowEx. So, you could try to hook these calls in the applications you are monitoring. But why do want this behaviour at all? The applications that let their taskbutton flash do that deliberate, because stealing the focus is much more intrusive for the user.

Comment: I guess [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305646/detecting-a-taskbar-icon-flashing) already handles your question. So it's a duplicate.